# Postgres: Build select Query from output of a query

Tags: postgresql

I have a Table named TEST with column name col1, col2, col3,col4..........
So, from information_schema.columns i will get details about this table object.

Now, i want to build a select query from TEST table by supplying colum name from information_schema.columns.
like this, select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'TEST'.This will return

## column_name

col1
col2
col3

i want to use this output in select query from TEST. Like  this 
select col1, col2,col3,col4 from TEST.

Is this possible by single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to compose an SQL string and execute that.

You can either do that with your client application or in a PostgreSQL function.

You must take special care to escape all string values using the [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#functions-string-format) function or [`quote_ident` and `quote_literal`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#plpgsql-quote-literal-example) to avoid problems from SQL injection.